# ARM M4 based Microcontroller or Particle Photon drive multiple small colour lcds?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, lcd

Hi I was just wondering if anyone had an example of running multiple small colour lcds from an arm based microcontroller or photon?

I'm hoping to run up to 5 lcds with photos.

Ideally if I could transfer the image data via http, store them and the display them when necessary that would be ideal.

I'm from a software side and trying to work out where to start hardware wise..

Answer (score 1):

First off it starts with pin count and the interfaces being used for these lcds. If they are spi for example, which some are that I have purchased.  Then sure, not a problem, you need between 8 and 20 pins depending on how many you can get per spi bus.  Same answer for i2c but fewer pins.  If these are lcs that take tens of pins each, then probably not you need something else or multiple microcontrollers.  which may be the solution anyway since the cost of a microcontroller relative to the lcd begins to disappear as you increase the size/complexity/performance of the lcd.

You also need some network solution as you implied you want a web server or client.  Can be solved with any of the IoT support chips these days, but not sure what you are truly after.

And you need enough storage for these photos, perhaps you can get by with only needing to store one or a fraction of one at a time as you pass it from the network packet solution to the lcd solution, or worst case you may need N lcds * 2 * biggest image if you need to have the currently displayed image plus a new image being downloaded double buffer style.

Answer (score 0):

What is the total pixel count of all the displays combined? Do you plan to use some effects or allow some digital image processing (include better scaling algorithm?) You may need to use something more advanced, like arranging all LCDs into one big virtual screen with HDMI input, and drive it using a full-blown GPU on a full-blown PC.